# Codeigniter how to csrf validation?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am new in codeigniter how to validate CSRF token inside a form.

**My form is:**

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/create_cta', array('class' => 'navbar-form navbar-left', 'id' => 'new-cta')); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="url" class="form-control" id="navbar-search-input" name="url" placeholder="Enter a URL">
                <span class="form-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">Create CTA</button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**config.php**

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function create_cta()
    {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        var_dump($data);
    }

}
```

**I Am not getting csrf input value. Here it is "var_dump($data);" result.**

```
array (size=1)
  'url' => string 'https://www.google.co.in/' (length=25)
```

Comment: Check generated form html. Do you have csrf-field there?

Comment: use form_open() inside your form

Comment: Just to eyeball its being created... With your Browser, view the page and then inspect the source... Look at the generated form code and see if the csrf token is included in the form in question.

Comment: Please tell me how to do csrf validate?

Answer (score -1):

You can get Csrf token value like,

```
$csrf = array(
    'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
    'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
);

...

<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
```

Refer this Link https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html

Comment: This does not answer the question: How to validate the CSRF **token name** and **hash**? Your post only mentioned how to generate those values.

Comment: yes, it's not an answer. it shows how to implement it in form view. The question is how to validate CSRF in post data handle in the controller